# Is data still available if 2 Cassandra nodes go down with RF=2?

Tags: cassandra

I'm newbie to C*, so can anyone please help. Suppose, in my environment there is a cluster of 6 nodes and a keyspace with RF=2. One day, two out of six nodes are down, so can I get data from the other 4 nodes (maybe) I lost data of some entries on two) and how do that?

Thanks.

Comment: At the very end of your question, what does "... and how do that?" mean? To be honest, I'm not sure what you're really asking. 

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! If it's your first time, it's not always easy to know how to ask questions. If it helps, have a look at https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask. 

Comment: Sorry if my question was not clear. I want to ask in a cluster with 6 nodes that has a keyspace with RF=2 when 2 nodes are down, can query the data of the remaining 4 nodes?

Comment: Worth mentioning, but remember that with RF=2, the only consistency levels which are useful for surviving a node down scenario is `ONE` and `LOCAL_ONE`.  After all, `QUORUM` of 2 == 2, so any request for data which has only one active replica will fail.

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends on a few factors but mostly on whether the two unavailable nodes are "neighbours" of each other. Let me illustrate with an example.

Consider this cluster with the following token assignments:

- `node1` owns token range 0-9
- `node2` owns 10-19
- `node3` owns 20-29
- `node4` owns 30-39
- and so on

Recall the copies are stored on the "neighbouring node" so with `RF=2`, the data for `node1` is replicated to `node2` (its neighbour), `node2` data is replicated to `node3` and so on.

Let's assume that we want to retrieve the data for `user = 'alice'` which is owned by `node1`. Here are the possible scenarios:

1. If we query with a consistency level of `LOCAL_QUORUM` (2 replicas must respond), and both `node1` and `node5` are down, then the read request will fail because both replicas (`node1` and `node2`) must respond but only `node2` is available.
2. If we query with `LOCAL_QUORUM`, and both `node1` and `node2` are down then the read will fail because both replicas are down.
3. If we query with `LOCAL_QUORUM`, and both `node3` and `node4` are down (not owners of the data) then the read request will return the data.
4. If we query with `LOCAL_ONE` and the coordinator picks `node1` but it is down, the read request will fail. It doesn't matter that `node2` is available because with `LOCAL_ONE`, only one node will be queried.
5. If we query with `LOCAL_ONE`, the coordinator picks `node1`, and `node2` is down, the data will get returned. It doesn't matter that `node2` is down because only one node (`node1`) will be queried.

If you'd like to know more about reads and consistency levels, see the following documents:

- [How read requests are accomplished in Cassandra](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra-oss/3.x/cassandra/dml/dmlClientRequestsRead.html)
- [Examples of read consistency levels](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra-oss/3.x/cassandra/dml/dmlClientRequestsReadExp.html)

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

> in a cluster with 6 nodes that has a keyspace with RF=2 when 2 nodes are down, can query the data of the remaining 4 nodes?

So, with RF=2 in a 6 node cluster (number of nodes doesn't really matter), there will be two copies of all data spread around those nodes.  Each node will have its own primary token ranges, along with a set of secondary ranges to hold additional data copies from the other nodes.

In the scenario described above, there are likely data partitions which have their primary and secondary copies on both of those nodes.  So, with RF=2 and 2 nodes down, Cassandra can no longer guarantee 100% data availability.

The 4 remaining nodes can still serve their data.  But requests for data whose tokens are both in the primary and secondary ranges for the 2 "DN" nodes will fail.